# Gmail caught in infinite loop, keep getting emails, please

Tags: google-apps-script

I have a script that generates notes for me and something hit out of place and created a never ending loop of emails to my account.  I deleted the project, columns and permissions but it keeps sending the emails, anymore know how I can stop it???

Comment: Go into the security settings, and you will find a list of Apps Script projects that you have given permissions to.  See if it's still in that list.  Even though you deleted the project, is it still in the trash?  Is it a bound script?  Stack Overflow isn't the place to get help for this issue.  Try the Apps Script community first: [Link to Apps Script group](https://plus.google.com/communities/102471985047225101769)

Comment: I deleted the script, but the gsheet is still in my drive because I need to keep it.  And thanks for the link!, I posted it there as well.  I don't understand how it's still runninf???

Comment: I deleted the script, but the gsheet is still in my drive because I need to keep it.   @

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend removing the contents of the file and building a new Spreadsheet. I do not know how Google handles recursive loops, but you might keep getting e-mails for some time. I know I have some large scripts that have errored out over the span of hours in the Google Scripts arena.

Also, for future development, nest all outward API pushes (e.g. e-mails, Drive manipulation, etc) in error handling to prevent this type of activity.

You may also be able to see what's going on if you get an error message to your e-mail from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com. This is Google's error messaging service, external to the script itself. This should at least give you some information about what is going on.

If you deleted the script entirely you may have limited options to stop the script using Google's Script UI.

Comment: Ok, thank you.  Do you know if any example for future error handling?  Just some type of counter?